# Database structure for tracking data across time

Tags: mysql, database-design

I wish to build a `MySQL database` that will track information across time `(once a day)`.

For example, `a list of URLs`, and several parameters related to the URL for which I wish to track the values every day.

So I am thinking of a data structure as follows:

```
URL-ID {
  {
    URL,
    Date { value_parameter1, value_parameter2 }
}
```

As this is the first time I am working with a time-based information database, I would appreciate some guidance. In particular:

- is the data structure I mention above a good way to start? or what would we your recommendation?
- what MySQL data Type is usually used for the Date parameter, in similar project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is called [Slowly Changing Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension), type `4`. Yes, it is legitimate and usable.

To tell if it fits your needs we would need to know a little more about your model.

To store dates, you should use type `DATE`.